# Running rake tasks without loading all production gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I was a little surprised this wasn't a common request - or maybe it's just hard to google on.  But here's what I'm trying to do.

I'd like to be able to run rake tasks in production environment without loading all the gems we use in that environment.  We have a lot of front-end specific gems, along with many others that just aren't needed. Is there a way to run rake, load up the production environment, but restrict the gems to a specific set?

Answer (score 0):

The Zeus gem loads rails applications in seconds: https://github.com/burke/zeus.

Also, this railscast might be helpful: http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands